# Dissolve Overlapping Polygons using difference and union in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, rgeo-shapefile

Have the shape file which has multiple polygons with logical division of Zones and Plots. Plots are overlapping over Zones. The task is to dissolve / merge plots with Zones with no overlapping.

[image] Here is spplot of the shape file. Here plots are on top of the Field Zones.
Also here is the shapefile with overlapped polygons (Zones & Plots): [Shapefile](http://www.filedropper.com/shapefile)

In QGIS, the same was achieved using Extracting the the Zones & Plots, Finding the difference and then dissolving using Union.Now need to program the same in R.

Tried below steps in R but would not able to get the right results , looking for ways how to dissolve this type of overlapping ploygons in R:

```
library(sp);
library(raster);
library(rgeos)

#Importing the shape files

field_boundary_fp <- "Database/gadenstedt2_outer_field 3 -26_0_zoned-plotm.shp"
poly_map_proj_str <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
utm_target_proj   <- "+init=epsg:32632";

field_boundary_sdf <- maptools::readShapePoly(fn = field_boundary_fp,
                                          proj4string =  CRS(poly_map_proj_str),
                                          repair = T,
                                          delete_null_obj = T,
                                          verbose = T);
spplot(
field_boundary_sdf,"Rx"
)

# Extracting the Zones and Plots#

Zone_sdf <- field_boundary_sdf[field_boundary_sdf@data$Type == "Zone", ]
Plot_sdf <- field_boundary_sdf[field_boundary_sdf@data$Type == "Plot", ]
plot(Plot_sdf)
plot(Zone_sdf)

#Finding the Intersection Part between the both
test <- gIntersection(Zone_sdf, Plot_sdf,id="ZoneIdx")
plot(test)
plot(test, add = T, col = 'blue')

# Finding the difference

test2 <- gDifference(Zone_sdf,Plot_sdf,id="ZoneIdx")
plot(test2)
plot(test2, add = T, col = 'red')

#Trying for Union then
polygon3 <- gUnion(test2, Plot_sdf,id="ZoneIdx")
plot(polygon3)
plot(polygon3, add = T, col = 'yellow')
```

Comment: We don't have your data and so we can't run your code, so we can't see where it is going wrong. Please update your question.

Comment: Thank you  @Spacedman for the response. Have uploaded the shapefile which has polygons and associated data. Link : http://www.filedropper.com/shapefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the shapefile

```
library(raster)
fields <- shapefile("gadenstedt2_outer_field 3 -26_0_zoned-plotm.shp")
```

First separate the zones and fields.

```
zone <- fields[fields$Type == "Zone", ]
plot <- fields[fields$Type == "Plot", ]
```

Erase plot from the zone

```
d <- erase(zone, plot)
```

Then append `plot` to `d`

```
r <- bind(plot, d)
```

And now aggregate

```
rd <- aggregate(r, "Rx")
spplot(rd, "Rx")
```

---- Now with a reproducible example, so that others can also benefit; you should not ask questions that depend on a file that needs to be downloaded ----

Example data (two SpatialPolygonDataFrame objects)

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
p <- aggregate(p, "NAME_1")
p$zone <- 10 + (1:length(p))
r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=2, vals=1:4, ext=extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), crs=crs(p))
names(r) <- "zone"
b <- as(r, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')
```

erase and append

```
e <- erase(p, b)
pb <- bind(e, b)

data.frame(pb)
#        NAME_1 zone
#1     Diekirch   11
#2 Grevenmacher   12
#3   Luxembourg   13
#4         <NA>    1
#5         <NA>    2
#6         <NA>    3
#7         <NA>    4
```

Comment: Thank you Robert for the answer. The Intersect gives only the plots and zones intersecting plots. Would also need remaining zones part also with that such that plots and zones are dissolved

Comment: Thanks again Robert but added Zones does not have the data values like the plot- Rx value will needed for Biomass Zone identification in Field

Comment: Thank you again Robert for the update. Before putting answer as correct, I went ahead to analyze the data and found that "Rx" values for plots are now same as zones. Plots "Rx" value should remain intact as we have for Zones now after dissolving plots & zones. Could you please assist on that.

Comment: I simplified and now it does that. It was hard to understand your question exactly (your use of the term "dissolving" is incorrect).

Comment: could be because of my naive knowledge at shape files side. The idea about whole exercise is to avoid overlapping of zones & plots and Rx values remain intact for both plots & remaining zones (in which plots are not there). Based on latest answer imported shape file (fields) and generated shape file (r) looks alike.Hope this gives you more information.

Comment: Oh, so you *do* want a *dissolve*. How about the current solution?

Comment: Thank you Robert.... This looks promising I will analyze more tonight and let you know

Comment: The solution worked for attached shape file. Then I tried the same solution for another test file to enable as generic solution but end result looked different. Could you please look into the same and reason , Am I missing something : http://www.filedropper.com/testingfile

Answer (score 0):

To ensure Solution works on all Fields , added an extra line of code to above solution to add Buffer Geometry.

```
fields <- gBuffer(fields, byid=TRUE, width=0) # Expands the given geometry to include 
the area within the specified width 

zone <- fields[fields$Type == "Zone", ]
plot <- fields[fields$Type == "Plot", ]

d <- erase(zone, plot)
spplot(d, "Rx")

r <- bind(plot, d)

rd <- aggregate(r, "Rx")

spplot(rd, "Rx")
```